Use Apple's FileMerge from command line and have it wait instead of exiting immediately
This question is a follow-up to Open two files for comparison in FileMerge, from command line.
After installing XCode, I can run opendiff dir1 dir2 on my Mac and get a nice GUI for comparing the dirs.
However, the command-line opendiff exits immediately, before I'm done editing the file. This prevents me from using opendiff and a diff editor or a merge editor for jj.
Question: Is there a way to get it to pause until the user is done editing, similarly to how VS Code's code --wait works (and all the Linux tools)?

Running opendiff without arguments shows its usage as usage: opendiff file1 file2 [-ancestor ancestorFile] [-merge mergeFile], which is a bit disappointing.
Just for kicks, here's a screenshot of the tool:


Instead of launching FileMerge via opendiff you can launch it with the open command (found here on Stack Overflow):
open -a FileMerge -n -W --args -left file1 -right file2

The -n option causes open to launch a new instance of the application even if one is already running, and the -W option causes open to wait until the application has exited.
The paths passed to the FileMerge application must be absolute. A wrapper script might be useful, something like
#!/bin/sh
file1=$(realpath "$1")
file2=$(realpath "$2")
open -a FileMerge -n -W --args -left "$file1" -right "$file2"

You may want to add error checking (number of parameters) and support for the -ancestor and -merge parameters, if needed.

Thank you! This seems to work. It's a bit annoying how you have to exit the whole app in a non-Apple-y way to quit, but this approach works much better than all the other alternatives I know.

@IlyaGrigoriev: My favorite "GUI diff tool" is BBEdit, called as '/usr/local/bin/bbdiff --wait --resume file1 file2

Thanks, I might try it! It seems to be a free feature of BBEdit, too, even though I'd have to use the 30-day trial to try it (and to see if the free version works for me). The advantage to FileMerge is that most developers will already have it installed (whether or not they know it)

@IlyaGrigoriev: Yes, it works with the free version of BBEdit.

If there is no better answer, here is a workaround that sort-of works. I have this generic shell script called pause_after in my PATH:
#!/bin/sh
"$@"
ERRCODE=$?
printf '\033[01;32m' # Green color
printf "\`%s\` exited with error code %s. Press Enter to continue, ^D to fail. " "$1" "$ERRCODE"
printf '\033[00m'    # Reset color
read -r __unused || (echo "(Got EOF or ^D)"; false)

You can then use pause_after opendiff ... instead of opendiff. You'll have to manually press ENTER in the terminal after opendiff exists.
